# problem making page scrollable horizontally

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have created a page containing a DeafultTabController in the middle of the screen. And then a list of texts at the bottom of the page, the text list at the bottom will be more than the screen allows, and I want the WHOLE PAGE to be scrollabe not just the bottom.

I have tried with ListView, CustomScrollView, but the screen just turns black.

[image]

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

class profilePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  profilePageState createState() => profilePageState();
}

class profilePageState extends State<profilePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: DefaultTabController(
        length: 3,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(),
          body: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              // construct the profile details widget here
              FractionallySizedBox(
                alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                widthFactor: 0.5,
                child: Container(
                  height: 200,
                  color: Colors.red,
                  width: double.infinity,
                  child: Column(
                    children: [Text("demo info")],
                  ),
                ),
              ),

              // the tab bar with three items
              SizedBox(
                height: 78,
                child: AppBar(
                  bottom: TabBar(
                    tabs: [
                      Tab(
                        iconMargin: EdgeInsets.all(2),
                        icon: Icon(Icons.directions_bike),
                        text: "Bike",
                      ),
                      Tab(
                        iconMargin: EdgeInsets.all(2),
                        icon: Icon(
                          Icons.directions_car,
                        ),
                        text: "Car",
                      ),
                      Tab(
                        iconMargin: EdgeInsets.all(2),
                        icon: Icon(
                          Icons.directions_boat,
                        ),
                        text: "Boat",
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),

              

              Container(
                height: 350,
                child: TabBarView(
                  children: [
                    // first tab bar view widget
                    Container(
                      color: Colors.red,
                      child: Center(
                        child: Text(
                          'Bike',
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),

                    // second tab bar viiew widget
                    Container(
                      color: Colors.pink,
                      child: Center(
                        child: Text(
                          'Car',
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    // third  tab bar view widget
                    Container(
                      color: Colors.pink,
                      child: Center(
                        child: Text(
                          'Boat',
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),

              Column(
                children: [
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                    children: [
                      Text("this needs to be fixed"),
                      Text("end data data"),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                    children: [
                      Text("this needs to be fixed"),
                      Text("end data data"),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                    children: [
                      Text("this needs to be fixed blabla"),
                      Text("end data data"),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                    children: [
                      Text("this needs to be fixed"),
                      Text("end data data"),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                    children: [
                      Text("this needs to be fixed bla bla "),
                      Text("end data data"),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                    children: [
                      Text("this needs to be fixed bla la "),
                      Text("end data data"),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try wrappping the first column with SingleChildScrollView, and make sure all of your columns have mainAxisSize=MainAxisSize.min to avoid infinite height

Comment: Thank you, that did it!  from what I could see, the mainAxisSize=MainAxisSize.min was not necessary.